# wanted to change default format of textbox textmode=time to 24 hour format

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In this textbox with textmode=time but the default format is 12 hours,wanted to change this default format to 24hr

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `HH` instead of `hh` for *24-hour format* date, i.e `dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm`